# Conditional replacement with SED

Tags: replace, sed, conditional-statements

I'm new to SED and have what may be a simple question. I've used it before to replace and delete characters but this is a little different. I need to eliminate commas within quotations, then eliminate the quotations in a csv file. So this:

```
"5,196,386","99,017",493,21
```

should end up looking like this:

```
5196386,99017,493,21
```

Answer (score 1):

gnu awk one-liner:

```
awk -v FPAT='([^,]+|"[^"]+")' -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)gsub(/[",]/,"",$i)}7'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  awk -v FPAT='([^,]+|"[^"]+")' -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)gsub(/[",]/,"",$i)}7' <<< '"5,196,386","99,017",493,21'
5196386,99017,493,21
```

Comment: +1 - as soon as text manipulation becomes more convolved, reach for `awk` as a first reflex (or perl).

Comment: thx @Floris, in fact the braces could be saved. (FPAT), making the cmd 2 chars shorter.

Comment: Note that `FPAT` is a feature of GNU `awk` not necessarily present in other versions of `awk`; it is not specified by POSIX.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, I think I mentioned that at the very beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do that with multiple `s///` operations.  The first will eliminate the commas between pairs of quotes when there are only commas and digits between the quotes; the second will eliminate the quotes (which by now have only digits between them):

```
 sed -e 's/"\([0-9][0-9]*\),\([0-9,][0-9,]*\)"/"\1\2"/g' \
     -e 's/"\([0-9][0-9]*\),\([0-9,][0-9,]*\)"/"\1\2"/g' \
     -e 's/"\([0-9][0-9]*\)"/\1/g'
```

You have to repeat the first operation as often as the maximum number of commas that can appear between quotes.  If your values go into the billions, you'll need a third copy of it.

Comment: Could you not simplify `[0-9][0-9]*` to `[0-9]+` or even `\d+`...?

Comment: It depends on which sub-species of `sed` you are working with.  I'm working with the notation that'll work with any `sed` that conforms to POSIX; you're proposing extensions that work with other variants of `sed`.

Comment: I did not realize that `+` was [not part of the "lowest common denominator" of BRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) - thanks for clarifying that. It did surprise me that you wrote it this way, which is why I asked the question. Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a language with a proper CSV parser. For example:

```
echo '"5,196,386","99,017",493,21' | 
ruby -rcsv -ne 'CSV.parse($_) do |row| 
  puts CSV.generate_line(row.map {|e| e.delete(",")})
end'
```

```
5196386,99017,493,21
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with nearly all `awk`

```
echo '"5,196,386","99,017",493,21' | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=""} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i=="\"") {f=!f;$i=""}; if (f && $i==",") $i=""}}1'
5196386,99017,493,21
```

---

How does it work:

```
awk '
BEGIN {                     # Begin block
    FS=OFS=""}              # Set input and output Field separator to "" (nothing) makes loop work on every characters
    {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {  # Looping trough line, one and one character at the time
        if ($i=="\"") {     # If a double quote is found do:
            f=!f            # Swap the flag "f" (If "f" is true, you are inside a double quote string
            $i=""}          # Delete the double quote
        if (f && $i==",")   # If "f" is true and we find a comma "," (inside a double quote string):
        $i=""}              # Delete the comma
    }
1                           # Print the line.
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/"[0-9,]+"/\n&\n/;T;h;s/[,"]//g;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/;ta' file
```

This puts `\n` markers round a double quoted field, makes a copy of the whole line, removes double quotes and commas, then puts the line back together again and repeats till no more changes are needed.

An alternative method:

```
sed -r 's/^/\n/;ta;:a;s/\n+$//;t;s/\n\n"/\n/;ta;s/\n"/\n\n/;ta;s/\n\n,/\n\n/;ta;s/(\n+)(.)/\2\1/;ta' file
```

Passes character by character through the string using a `\n` as marker. Two `\n`'s marks when the next character is within a quoted field.

Answer (score 0):

```
    awk '{gsub(/"5,196,386","99,017"/,"5196386,99017")}1' file
5196386,99017,493,21
```